# useContext null error when building React App using Styled-Components (Rollup/WebPack)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, styled-components, rollupjs

Trying to build any simple React app using styled-components will result in the errors from the image below:[image]

Currently, I am using rollup (have tried with webpack, but it's the same). Below is my:

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "SC-Test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "lib/index.js",
    "module": "lib/index.esm.js",
    "types": "lib/index.d.ts",
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.22.10",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
        "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.3",
        "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.3",
        "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.1.0",
        "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^5.0.2",
        "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.2",
        "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.1.4",
        "postcss": "^8.4.27",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "rollup": "^3.28.0",
        "rollup-plugin-dts": "^5.3.1",
        "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
        "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
        "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
        "styled-components": "^6.0.7"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "styled-components": "^6.0.7"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "rollup -c"
    }
}
```

The `rollup.config.mjs`

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
// To handle css files
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";

import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";

import packageJson from "./package.json" assert { type: "json" };
import path from "path";

export default [
    {
        input: "src/index.js",
        output: [
            {
                file: packageJson.main,
                format: "cjs",
                sourcemap: true,
            },
            {
                file: packageJson.module,
                format: "esm",
                sourcemap: true,
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            peerDepsExternal(),
            resolve({
                extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
                browser: true,
                alias: {
                    react: path.resolve("./node_modules/react"),
                },
                // dedupe: ['react', 'react-dom'],
            }),
            babel({
                exclude: "node_modules/**",
                presets: [["@babel/preset-react", { runtime: "automatic" }]],
                plugins: [
                    ["babel-plugin-styled-components", { displayName: true }],
                ],
            }),
            commonjs(),
            postcss(),

            terser(),
        ],
        external: ["react", "react-dom", "styled-components"],
    },
];
```

The `index.js`

```
export { default as Test } from "./Test.jsx";
```

The `Test.jsx`

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledDiv = styled.div`
    background-color: red;
`;

const Test = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            This is the main div
            <StyledDiv>This is the styled div</StyledDiv>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Test;
```

After using the build command, I want to link the app using yarn link with another React app, but when using the Test component by `import {Test} from 'SC-Test'`, I get the errors below.

I have tried webpack and rollup, but the issue seems to be related whether to React 18 or styled-components v5/v6.